# Hibernate join cannot cast exception many to many

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I got a question regarding hibernate. 
I have to classes with many to many relationship and try to make a select. The problem is I am getting an exception. Can you help?

```
@Entity(name = "pracownik")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Pracownik extends Osoba {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "grafikpracownika", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idosoby") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idgrafiku") })
private List<Grafik> grafiki = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The second entity

```
@Entity (name = "grafik")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Grafik {

@ManyToMany (mappedBy = "grafiki",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List <Pracownik> pracownik  = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

The method I developed is:

```
    public List<Pracownik> getWszyscyPracownicyGrafiku() {
    List<Pracownik> pracownicy = new ArrayList<>();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from pracownik as p join p.grafiki");
    pracownicy = query.list();
    transaction.commit();
    return pracownicy;
}
```

And the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.Pracownik
```

Any idea what is wrong? 

I also would like to add a "where" but it should be easy after I get rid of this exception. 
I also tried with "normal" sql

```
SELECT * from pracownik p join grafikpracownika g on p.idosoby = g.idosoby where idgrafiku = 6
```

but what I am getting is:

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [idosoby] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting from two tables without explicit `select` clause, therefore Hibernate produces a list of tuples `(Pracownik, Grafik)` as a result.

If you want only `Pracownik`s (i.e. join is needed to create condition on `p.grafiki` in `where`), use

```
select distinct p from pracownik as p join p.grafiki
```

If join is used to instruct Hibernate to fetch associated `Grafik`s, use `join fetch`:

```
from pracownik as p join fetch p.grafiki
```